# How do you fix a Rails server boot up that's freezing or not continuing to boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I tried booting up a Rails server but I'm stuck with this :

```
$ rails s --port=3400
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: hmm... `puma -p 3400` ...? (I'm assuming, since that's how I start `iodine`)... maybe with Rails, `rails s -- -p 3400`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you actually querying your port 3400 ? Because the Rails server does not seem to throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the **webpacker**, I tried installing a different rails app it's working without webpacker, I'm trying to find a way on how can i solve this webpacker workflow.